# Rails Restricting Access to a PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, restrict

I have a app that uploads pdfs to the public directory.  Most of the time these will be accessed through a link but each pdf will have an allowed user list of who can view these pdfs (they're resumes so not everyone should be able to view a student's personal information).

The resumes are currently stored under /public/resumes/:id/name.pdf using the paperclip gem for upload and deletion.

The links work fine and take you to the resume and will not be normally visible to people who don't have access to them, however, if you know the direct URL of the pdf you are able to type that in and get to it whether you're logged in or not.

How would I go about making the pdf check access before showing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd link to a download action and check there using [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file)

```
def download
  @resume = resume.find(params[:id])
  if current_user and @resume.user_ids.include?(current_user.id)
    send_file @resume.pdf
  else
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'You don't have required access'
  end
end
```

Comment: you probably want to use a Boolean operator `&&` not  control flow `and` since you are evaluating the expressions as true or false via `if`